# How to directly calculate desired phase shift of signals?

Tags: matlab, fft, octave, combinatorics, algebraic-data-types

I'm comparing 2 combined phase shifted signals (*x_phase_sig_comb*) to a given signal (*x_given*).
At the moment I'm using a `for` loop to add together each and every combined phase shifted signal (*x_phase_sig_comb*) and then I calculate the RMSE (root mean square error) value with respect to the given signal (*x_given*) I then place each value into an array and then I sort for the least RMSE (Root mean square error value).

**Is there an algebraic way to directly calculate the phase shift at which the 2 combined phase shifted signals (*x_phase_sig_comb*) will have the least, largest, or a selected range of RMS (root mean square error) when compared to that of a given signal (*x_given*).  I'm trying to avoid having to calculate each and every combined phase shifted signal (*x_phase_sig_comb*)**

The reason I ask is that I have signals that are very large and to loop through each one would take a considerable amount of time.  Directly calculating the phase shift that would give me the least, largest or a range of RMSE values with respect to (*x_given*) using some type of algebric "form" would save a considerable amount of time.  I just don't know how to constrain the frequency and amplitude of the phase shifted signals or how to algebraically do this. any ideas?

I created an animation below showing the two signals being phase shifted along with the RMSE values with respect to the (*x_given*) signal. **Note: the two signals on the top plot are the same the only difference is one signal is being phase shifted to the left and the other signal is being phase shifted to the right.**

[image: animated gif]

Ps: I'm using octave 4.0 which is similar to matlab
See example code below

```
%test compare signals

Fs = 100;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 100;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
t_plot=linspace(0,Fs,Fs);     %used just for plotting

x = .5*sin(2*pi*10*t)+0.7*sin(2*pi*12.3*t) +.4*sin(2*pi*16.5*t); %main signal
x_given=.4*sin(2*pi*15*t); %given signal to compare it to
data_array=[];

for rr=1:1:100
  x_sig_main_a = circshift(x(:),rr); %shift signal to the right
  x_sig_main_b = circshift(x(:),-rr); %shift signal to the left
  x_phase_sig_comb=x_sig_main_a+x_sig_main_b; %combine shifted signals together

  NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of siganl
  Y = fft(x_phase_sig_comb,NFFT)/L;
  freq = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

  %find maximum value, it should be the fundamental frequency (approximated)
  [maxidx,maxVal]=max(2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)));
  freq(maxVal); %max frequency value

  %RMSE
  dy = abs(x_phase_sig_comb(:)-x_given(:)); %absolute error
  MAE  = mean(dy); %mean-absolute-error
  MXE = max(dy); %maximum-absolute-error
  RMSE = sqrt(mean(dy.^2));  %   root-mean-sqare-error 

  %data_tmp=[rr,freq(maxVal)];
  data_tmp=[rr,RMSE];
  data_array=[data_array;data_tmp];

   % Plot .
  subplot(2,1,1);
  plot(t_plot,x_sig_main_a,'-r',t_plot,x_sig_main_b,'-b')
  s1 = strcat('Phase Shift of 2 signals',' - (',num2str(rr),' bits) shifted out of 100' );
  titletxt = {s1};

  title(titletxt,'FontSize',14);

  subplot(2,1,2); plot(data_array(rr,1),data_array(rr,2),'*-r') 
  axis([0 100 0 1.5])
  s1 = strcat('RMSE of 2 combined phase shifted signals to the given signal =',num2str(data_array(rr,2)));
  titletxt = {s1};
  hold on

  title(titletxt,'FontSize',14);
  xlabel('Phase shift of signals')
  ylabel('Root Mean Square Erro')

  pause(.01)
end
subplot(2,1,2); plot(data_array(:,1),data_array(:,2),'*-r'); %connect lines in plot 
data_array_sort = sortrows(data_array,2); %sort by least different 2 
data_array_sort(1:3,:) %Similar combined phase shifted signals to x_given signal
```

**Is there an algebraic way to directly calculate the phase shift at which the 2 combined phase shifted signals (*x_phase_sig_comb*) will have the least, largest or a selected range of RMS (root mean square error) when compared to that of a given signal (*x_given*).  I'm trying to avoid having to calculate each and every combined phase shifted signal (*x_phase_sig_comb*)**

The reason I ask is that I have signals that are very large and to loop through each one would take a considerable amount of time.  Directly calculating the phase shift that would give me the least, largest, or a range of RMSE values with respect to (*x_given*) using some type of algebric "form" would save a considerable amount of time.  I just don't know how to constrain the frequency and amplitude of the phase shifted signals or how to algebraically do this. any ideas?

Comment: I understand that you have two signals, a “given” one and a “main” one and that you’re trying to somehow match the given one to be as close to the main one (in RMS-sense) as possible. But why are you delaying the main signal by `+rr` and `-rr` samples and adding them and comparing *that* to the given signal? Also, you are using the phrase “phase shift” to mean “shift”. Phase-shifting a signal is multiplying it by `exp(j*phi)`, but your code is just delaying. So which is it, phase shift or delay? What are you [**really** trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/262011)?

Comment: are you talking about cross-correlation?

Comment: @Ahmed Fasih It's a phase shift see video that explains phase shifting https://youtu.be/30J5U0ThRUc    the +rr and -rr represent what will be played in the left ear and right ear and combining the signals will give a binaural beat.

Comment: @RickT: The video you've linked only shows sinus signals with the same frequency. If you only have one frequency a delay has the same effect as a phase shift. As soon as you have multiple frequencies (as in you example above) a constant time delay is not the same as a phase shift, as Ahmed already said. I guess you want to figure out the time delay between two signals until the "match". This can be done using cross-correlation (see S Geurts answer)

Comment: @Andy thanks for the help and it would work except that in correlation one signal doesn't "move" see video https://youtu.be/RO8s1TrElEw but my signals are both moving in opposite "directions" at the same time `x_sig_main_a = circshift(x(:),rr);` %shift signal to the right
  `x_sig_main_b = circshift(x(:),-rr);` %shift signal to the left.  Can Correlation be adjusted to have both signals move in different directions at the same time?

Comment: @RickT: "moving in opposite directions" is just a matter of opinion. If you delay one and advance the other it gives the same (but shifted) correlation as if you delay one signal 2 steps and leave the other. I wonder why you are using circshift (and in constrast are talking about "phase shift") and I guess this is a XY-Problem http://xyproblem.info/. Perhaps you should instead explain what you are really trying to do.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, there's also http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use correlation in stead of RMS.

```
[Correlation,lag] = xcorr(x,x_given)
[~,index] = max(abs(Correlation))
timeshift = lag(index)
```

Documentation about de function [xcorr](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html#bugnq6o-1)

Comment: That just replaces 'RMS' with 'correlation' the main issue is I still would have to add together each and every combined phase shifted signal (x_phase_sig_comb) and then I calculate if not using RMSE use correlation.  The reason is that I have signals that are very large and to loop through each one would take a considerable amount of time. Directly calculating the phase shift that would give me the least, largest, or a range of RMSE / correlated values with respect to (x_given) using some type of algebraic "form" would save a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Correlation replaces your loop, so you don't need a loop. The max value of correlation corresponds with a certain time shift where both signals matches best (i changes some variable-names in my proposal to made it more clear). You can calculate the phase from the time-shift when you now the main frequency.

Comment: @S Geurts thanks for the help and it would work except that in correlation one signal doesn't "move" see video https://youtu.be/RO8s1TrElEw but my signals are both moving in opposite "directions" at the same time `x_sig_main_a = circshift(x(:),rr);` %shift signal to the right
  `x_sig_main_b = circshift(x(:),-rr);` %shift signal to the left.  Can Correlation be adjusted to have both signals move in different directions at the same time?

Comment: Why would you move both signals in both directions? Moving both signals  in opposite direction is the same as moving one signal twice as fast. So if you find a time-shift, using correlation, you have to divide it by 2, to find your time-shift.
But maybe it would help to explain your problem more complete. What do you want to achieve finally? Could you provide the real signals you are working with?

Comment: @S Geurts  the x_sig_main_a and x_sig_main_b represent what will be played in the left ear and right ear and `combining the signals will give a binaural beat`.  The signals are very large audio signals so trying to post 100 meg + files is not possible.  I'm trying to find the phase/bit shift needed between `x_sig_main_a` and `x_sig_main_b` when they are added together if given the `RMSE` or `Correlation value`